# No Continuous Mapping?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Exercise:
For [a,b] a nondegenerate closed, bounded interval, show that there is no continuous mapping from $ L^{1}[a,b]$ onto $ L^{\infty}[a,b] $.

My initial thought is to prove by contradiction.  Assuming that there indeed does exists a continuous mapping, say $f $, and then to use the definition of continuity by taking an open set in $L^{\infty}[a,b]$ and then show that it does not map to an open set in $L^1[a,b]$.  However, I'm a little stuck as to how to begin (or if there is a better approach to the problem).

Comment: Do you mean a linear map, or any map? For the first, you can use the open mapping theorem and the fact that $L^1$ is separable, whereas $L^{\infty}$ is not.

Comment: It can be any map.

Comment: Dear @user0430 I see that, although you have already asked 18 question in this site and received answers in most of them, you have not mark a best answer in any of them. You can do it so by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer that you think is the one that helped you the most. Please [read here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: let $X,Y$ be metric spaces. If $X$ is separable and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a continuous and surjective mapping, then $Y$ is separable. Now use the fact that $L^1[a,b]$ is separable, but $L^{\infty}[a,b]$ is not.